# ios open pdf in ibooks from DocumentsDirectory

Tags: ios, pdf, uidocumentinteraction, uti

I'm trying to open a pdf I generated and saved in my document directory with other applications like ibook with this code:

```
NSLog(@"Send PDF: %@", _pdfPath);
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_pdfPath];
docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
docController.UTI=@"com.adobe.pdf";   
BOOL isValid = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
```

It seem it has to work fine but when the popover pops ibooks is not in, I have other application but not ibooks. I know the PDF is well formatted because I can open it in preview. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have see a lot of tutorials but not found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the UTI, if you have iBooks installed it should appear in the pop up menu, are you sure you have iBooks installed?